# Install FreeBSD from Linux (without booting from USB or CD)

Tags: freebsd, dual-boot, system-installation

Is there a way to get FreeBSD installed along Linux, working directly from this running Linux (as opposed to booting from installation image on USB-stick / CD).

E.g. I suppose something like this:

- create partitions (`/boot`, `/root`, `swap` - right?) in free space
- then put some boot code / image onto boot (bsd) partition
- alter GRUB accordingly (seemingly there are enough instructions)
- probably also put necessary installation packages there
- now reboot to that "partial" installation of bsd and proceed from here (e.g. with bsdinstall or something like this)

Hopefully you get the idea. Please tell if this is doable and perhaps set my eyes onto some kind of instruction.

Comment: IMHO, no Linux tool is able to create BSD [slices](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/basics/#disk-organization) or [install boot code](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=boot0cfg&sektion=8).

Comment: @VladimirBotka and you probably mean none of suitable tools were ported? thanks, probably I should consider mounting partitions to VM or something like this then...

Comment: If I were going to try this, I'd simply create a partition to hold the BSD installation, then shutdown Linux, boot from the BSD installation media, and then take care to install BSD specifically into the designated partition.  About the only thing left would be hacking GRUB to find and load the BSD loader when a BSD boot is selected.

Comment: Right. This is a single installation. If the question is looking for a scalable procedure in Linux, maybe in mass production, I'd [customize the image](https://ansible-freebsd-custom-image.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) if needed, *dd* it to a partition, and [configure GRUB](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/booting-freebsd-via-grub.60422/) if needed (the FreeBSD disk might be used in a standalone device).